# Only bootstrap cards on small devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7. I have made a grid for a new website. The code for this can be [seen here](https://www.bootply.com/Mz757qmwBk).

I would like to set the grid elements in a bootstrap card, so it is looking like this:

**Screen bigger than 767px:**
[image]
**Screen smaller than 767px:**
[image: Screen 767px]

I am not sure how I get started on this. Should I try to merge the 2 codes from the grid element code(linked to above) and my card code? Should I start all over, because the code will be to messy if I start writing the 2 code documents together?

**Code for the Bootstrap Card:**

```css
 @media (max-width: 768px) {

     .index-content .col-lg-4 {
         margin-top: 20px;
     }

     .index-content a:hover{
     color:black;
     text-decoration:none;
  }
  .index-content{
      margin-bottom:20px;
      padding:50px 0px;
      
  }
  .index-content .row{
      margin-top:20px;
  }
  .index-content a{
      color: black;
  }
  .index-content .card{
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      padding:0;
      -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
      -moz-border-radius: 4px;
      border-radius:4px;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

  }
  .index-content .card:hover{
      box-shadow: 0 16px 24px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 6px 30px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
      color:black;
  }
  .index-content .card img{
      width:100%;
      border-top-left-radius: 4px;
      border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  }
  .index-content .card h4{
      margin:20px;
  }
  .index-content .card p{
      margin:20px;
      opacity: 0.65;
  }
  .index-content .blue-button{
      width: 100px;
      -webkit-transition: background-color 1s , color 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
      transition: background-color 1s , color 1s;
      min-height: 20px;
      background-color: #002E5B;
      color: #ffffff;
      border-radius: 4px;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: lighter;
      margin: 0px 20px 15px 20px;
      padding: 5px 0px;
      display: inline-block;
  }
  .index-content .blue-button:hover{
      background-color: #dadada;
      color: #002E5B;
  }
 }
```

```html
<div class="index-content">
        <div class="container">
                <a href="blog-ici.html">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nJ97Go/bmw.jpg"></img>
                            <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                            <a href="blog-ici.html" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
        </div>
    </div
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this? I just added a parent `div` for those contents and its position absolute on `min-width: 768px`

```css
.index-content a:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.index-content {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 50px 0px;
}

.index-content .row {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.index-content a {
  color: black;
}

.index-content .card {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.index-content .card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 16px 24px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 6px 30px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: black;
}

.index-content .card img {
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

.index-content .card h4 {
  margin: 20px;
}

.index-content .card p {
  margin: 20px;
  opacity: 0.65;
}

.index-content .blue-button {
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s, color 1s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: background-color 1s, color 1s;
  min-height: 20px;
  background-color: #002E5B;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin: 0px 20px 15px 20px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.index-content .blue-button:hover {
  background-color: #dadada;
  color: #002E5B;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .index-content .col-lg-4 {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    position: relative;
  }
  .card-content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  .card-content h4,
  .card-content p {
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
  }
  .card-content a {
    float: right;
  }
  .index-content .card h4,
  .index-content .card p {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .index-content .card p {
    padding: 0 20px 15px;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="index-content">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="blog-ici.html">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nJ97Go/bmw.jpg">


          <div class="card-content">
            <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            <a href="blog-ici.html" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
          </div>



        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No.... That is actually more than perfect. Way much more than I expected to do :) Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: Its happy to help you :)